# What does dollar followed by an index mean in a class name?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm profiling a java application, and the largest number of the allocated objects have name 
`com.x.y.ClassName$5`.

Both the netbeans profiler and the yourkit use the same naming convention.
I'm at loss how to google the naming problem.

What is `$5` after class name?

EDIT:
It seems the $5 is fifth anonymous class declared. I've used [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) on generated class to find which is the fifth anonymous class. Reference found in [How to match compiled class name to an enum member in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998861/how-to-match-compiled-class-name-to-an-enum-member-in-java)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

com.x.y.ClassName$5 means "the fifth anonymous inner class in com.x.y.ClassName"

Comment: Wow, quick answer. Is there a way how to tell which inner class is 5th?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that. So I'm not happy with my own answer. Saying "fifth" without saying the specific order is like saying "a random number". However, if you have a good decompiler like [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) can show you the code of any inner class

Comment: I think that it is the order in which they are declared... Anyway, you can overwrite the toString() to provide some meaningful representation in the debugger.

Comment: @fortran How will to toString method change Class name?

Comment: @bbaja42 it won't change the class name at all, but in most IDEs if you hover the mouse over a live object it will show its toString() representation (that by default is the class name and some hash).

Answer (score 1):

Some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075207/what-are-the-1-in-class-file) to help you. 
Also look at [polygenelubricant's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883181/why-is-an-anonymous-inner-class-containing-nothing-generated-from-this-code) answer

you get **com.x.y.ClassName$5**. when your  class contains a **anonyomous inner class**

```
    sample8.class
    sample8$1.class
    sample8$2.class
    sample8$klass.class
    sample8$klass$1.class
```

Example

```
   public class sample8 {


        private class klass{
            void vodka() {
                sample8 _s = new sample8() {

                };

            }
        }
        sample8() {
               klass _k = new klass();
              _k.vodka();
           }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }

    sample8 _s = new sample8() {

    };

    sample8 _s1 = new sample8() {

    };
}
```

Comment: AFAIK that would result in ClassName$klass, not in a ClassName$<a number>

Comment: thanks Mark you r right. If there is an anonyomous inner class, it creates one.